# Conflict of Packages in RStudio, detach() fails to work

Tags: r, package, detach

I am currently doing Logistic Regression on the  `'birthwt'` data set found within R. This data is found within the package  `'MASS'`.

However, when I use  `library(MASS)` to retrieve the data, it masks the function of  `select()` from the dplyr package. I use this function almost immediately in my analysis.

After loading the data, I attempt
`detach("package:MASS", unload = TRUE)`

but I am met with
`‘MASS’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘MASS’ is imported by ‘pbkrtest’, ‘car’, ‘lme4’ so cannot be unloaded`

I wold really love to sort this out as I have completed all my necessary analysis on the data, but was met with this issue when attempting to knit.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't choose `unload = TRUE`.  The default is `unload = FALSE`, and that's what you need.

Here's the explanation:

In R, packages can be "loaded", which makes them available to other packages that import functions from them.  They can also be "attached", which puts them on the search list, so that they are available to the user in the console.  If a package is attached, it needs to be loaded, but the reverse is not true.

So if you run `detach("package:MASS")`, you will remove it from the search list, and in the console, running `select()` will no longer find the function in MASS.  It will still be loaded, so will be available to the other packages that need it.

By the way, using the prefix form `MASS::select()` or `dplyr::select()` will work regardless of whether either or both packages are in your search list.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried `dplyr::select()` and works lovely!